# Tangent vector as velocity of curve that is in tangent space of manifold but not in the tangent space of submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry

This is the problem 5-19 from the second edition of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"  [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzWjk.png).

I need to see clear why is false if S is not embedded. I already know that the eight-figure in the plane works as counterexample but I can't do the formal proof.

Thanks for all in advance.

Comment: So what precisely have you done with the figure 8? Give us equations and the idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm trying to consider $\gamma : (-\pi,\pi) \to RxR = M$ defined by $\gamma (t) = sen(t) (cos(t),1)$ and $S:=\{ sen(t) (cos(t),1) : t \in (0,2 \pi)\}$. So, clearly $\gamma'(0) \in T_{\gamma(0)}RxR$ and intuitively $\gamma'(0) \notin T_{\gamma(0)}S$ but I can't fisnish to understand why and can't do a formal proof of that idea.

Comment: No, you need a different curve. Here of course you do have the tangent vector in the tangent space of $S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin how? Can give me an example please. Thank you.

Comment: You need to draw pictures and see precisely what $S$ looks like. You want a curve that goes through the figure-8 point of $S$ without following $S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin like a line with the same derivate of my $\gamma$ at the origin? And in this case, how I do to show the required?

Comment: I apologize. You were correct. I was reading on my phone instead of on my computer. Consider the parametrization $f\colon (0,2\pi)$ of $S$. The point $(0,0)=\gamma(0)$ appears in $S$ as $f(\pi)$, and so the tangent space of $S$ at the origin is spanned by $f'(\pi)$. How does this compare to $\gamma'(0)$? I hope you're actually drawing pictures.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm drawing pictures, actually is almost the unique that I can do. And sure, but why that's enough? Compared to $\gamma'(0)$ is perpendicular, but I don't know or can't understand why that it's sufficient. I'm really new in this geometry. I think that the argument is center in the fact that you say $f'(\pi)$ span that tangent space but is only by the parametrization?

Comment: So this is the point that $S$ is an immersed *but not embedded* submanifold. Your curve $\gamma$ passes through the origin in a completely different way than $S$ does, even though the image of $\gamma$ is entirely contained in $S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin really thank you!